# yii2 проблема с отправкой почты

Tags: yii2, phpmailer

Есть совершенно два одинаковых метода для отправки почты (регистрация нового пользователя, **отсылается письмо для активации пользователя**). Один метод реализован в консоли, и работает:

```
public function actionSendMessage()
    {
        $user = new User();
        $this->readValue($user, 'username');
        $this->readValue($user, 'login');
        $this->readValue($user, 'email');
        $user->hash_password = Yii::$app->getSecurity()->generatePasswordHash($this->prompt('password'));
        $this->readValue($user, 'phone');
        $this->readValue($user, 'address');;
        $user->state = User::STATUS_WAIT;
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->generateEmailConfirmToken();
        if ($user->save()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/emailConfirm', ['user' => $user])
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name])
                ->setTo($user->email)
                ->setSubject('Email confirmation for ' . Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        }
    }
```

Второй должен отсылать письмо при регистрации на сайте, но увы, письмо не приходит (**ошибок нет**):

```
public function sign()
    {

        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $this->username;
        $user->login = $this->login;
        $user->email = $this->email;
        $user->hash_password = yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($this->password);
        $user->phone = $this->phone;
        $user->address = $this->address;
        $user->state = User::STATUS_WAIT;
        $user->generateAuthKey();
        $user->generateEmailConfirmToken();
        if ($user->save()) {
            Yii::$app->mailer->compose('@app/mail/emailConfirm', ['user' => $user])
                ->setFrom([Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'] => Yii::$app->name])
                ->setTo($user->email)
                ->setSubject('Email confirmation for ' . Yii::$app->name)
                ->send();
        }

    }
```

> В чем может быть загвоздка?

Comment: 100% в моделе user ошибка, обработайте этот вариант, вызова валидации нет у вас совсем p.s. обратите внимание на метод load и attributs модели

Comment: @Ghost все в порядке и с `load` и с `attributes` (они одинаковые)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел причину. Нужно было изменить настройки в web.php. Письмо формировалось, но сохранялось в файл.